# How to put AVPlayer inside SCNPlane (ARKit)?

Tags: avplayer, arkit

I'm doing IOS app that recognize 2D image. After recognition it cover the area with read background using this code:

```
SCNPlane *plane = [SCNPlane planeWithWidth:width height:height];
plane.firstMaterial.diffuse.contents = [UIColor redColor];
```

Now I want it to play video inside this detected area. I created AVPlayer object using:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"IMG_2099" withExtension:@"MOV"];
AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:url];
```

and added player to material, replacing redColor with:

```
plane.firstMaterial.diffuse.contents = player;
```

I guess I need to do something else in order to make AVPlayer play. What should I add to the code (objective c)?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a SpriteKit scene, add a video node to it,  and make it the material of your SceneKit geometry.

Comment: Thank You. Can You reference to objective c example (not swift)?